# How Does WebElement.equals() Method Check for Equality?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I have more than 1 XPath pointing to a web element and I want to determine if both elements are equivalent (i.e, if I perform the action sendKeys() or click() on both web elements the action would be executed on the same web element) Currently I'm checking for equality using the following method:

```
    WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ap_email']"));
    WebElement element2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@type='email']"));


    System.out.println(element1.equals(element2));
```

This will return true as long as both XPath point to the same element.

However, I am unsure how the method determines equality? And are there any circumstances where the two web elements are in fact the same (i.e, any action carried out on them would be carried out on the same web element) but the method shows they are different? Or vice versa?

I am trying to develop a foolproof method to determine equality of two web elements.

I'm using Java and Selenium.

Comment: WebElement is an interface. You'd need to determine the type of the actual object you have. You can then likely locate source for that object online to see the equals() implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, I am unsure how the method determines equality?

The driver generates a reference for each encountered `HTMLElement` object in the document and always returns the same reference for an `HTMLElement` object.

This reference is stored in the `WebElement.id` property on the client side and has nothing to do with the id attribute used with a locator.

So to determine the equality between two `WebElement`, the client simply tests the reference stored in `WebElement.id`.

> And are there any circumstances where the two web elements are in fact the same but the method shows they are different?

Technically speaking, no it never happens and it would be a serious issue if it was the case.

But it kind of depends on what you mean by the same. For instance a button can look the same at two different moments, but may have been replaced by an identical one which would generate a new reference. This is the case when the page or some parts are reloaded:

```
  driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com/");

  WebElement elementA = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#logo"));
  WebElement elementB = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#logo"));

  boolean same1 = elementA.equals(elementB);  // return true

  elementB.click();  // reloads the page, all the previous web element are now obsolete

  WebElement elementC = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#logo"));

  boolean same2 = elementA.Equals(elementC);  // return false
```

Answer (score 1):

RemoteWebElement is the class that implements WebElement. The equals method compares the id variable, which is a String. If you create two WebElements even if they are pointing at the same element their id value will be different. Infact id is used as the haschcode also. You can check by printing out the id for both elements.

Comment: Thanks. Not all web elements have IDs (such as the username and password field on Entropay.com) how does RemoteWebElement compare them in this case?

Comment: This has nothing to do with CSS id on the html. This id is generated in the RemoteWebElement class. Check out the source code here - http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-remote-driver/2.47.1/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebElement.java

Comment: Also you mentioned "if you create two web elements even if they are pointing at the same element their id value would be different" this does not seem to be the case. In my previous example in main post there are two entirely different web elements (element1 and element2) and the equals() method returns true. Also if RemoteWebElement does not compare the HTML/CSS id on web page then what in fact are they comparing. I mean on what basis do they decide two elements are the same/different?

Comment: You are right they have the same id. So I guess the equals method will work even if they are created by different methods.

Answer (score 1):

Following is the equals implementation in RemoteWebElement which implements WebElement interface.

According to this method, two elements will be treated as equal if their ids are same, where id is returned from browser in response of findElement. So if we execute findElement using 2 different xpaths, you can check the id attribute from the element coming back in response. if the two ids are same, they will be treated as same element, if not they will be treated as different element.

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
if (!(obj instanceof WebElement)) {
  return false;
}

WebElement other = (WebElement) obj;
while (other instanceof WrapsElement) {
  other = ((WrapsElement) other).getWrappedElement();
}

if (!(other instanceof RemoteWebElement)) {
  return false;
}

RemoteWebElement otherRemoteWebElement = (RemoteWebElement) other;

return id.equals(otherRemoteWebElement.id);
```

}